# Is it possible to get all the history of reccuring google tasks with google tasks API?

Tags: python-3.x, google-tasks-api

I have a tasklist with repeating tasks inside. I managed to retrieve the tasks via google tasks API, but only for the current day. From the documentation I find it impossible to retrieve all the history of reccuring tasks. Am I missing something?

The idea is to create a script to keep a count of how successful a person is in doing his dailies, keeping a streak, maybe make a chart to see ratio of completed/not completed etc...

I used the google quickstart code and modified it a bit, but as much as I try, I can only get the reccuring tasks from that day... Any help?

```
    # Call the Tasks API
    results = service.tasks().list(tasklist='b09LaUd1MzUzY3RrOGlSUg', showCompleted=True,
                                   showDeleted=False, showHidden=True).execute()
    items = results.get('items', [])

    if not items:
        print('No task lists found.')
        return

    print('Task lists:')
    for item in items:
        print(item)
```

Comment: please add imports so that users can reproduce the problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Google task API doesn't provide the API to determine if one task is repeated or not. It will provide only one instance even if one task is repeated. They have one issue tracking page: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/273870211

So, you can't do that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).